# Help with converting inline onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, set, inline

I'm trying to convert some hard-coded inline onclicks to be dynamically created.

Here's what they look like now:

(html)

```
<ul id="search-navlist">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this,'A'); return false;">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this,'B'); return false;">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this,'C'); return false;">C</a></li>
....
    <li><a href="#" onclick="searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this,'Z'); return false;">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Here's the new code:**

(script)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-navlist li a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("onclick", "searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this,'A'); return false;");
    });
});
```

(in html)

```
<ul id="search-navlist">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    ....
    <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

So far, this works fine, although all of the links are the same. I'd like the links to be associated with it's respective letter.

I found this function:

```
function iterateAlphabet() {
    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
        alert(nextChar)
    }
}
```

...but am uncertain as to how to incorporate it. (I also saw some script using charcodes, the above function was easier for me to understand.)

I'd appreciate some help. I'll continue trying in the meantime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite as:

```
<ul id="search-navlist">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
....
    <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-navlist li a').click(function() {
        // alert($(this).text());
        searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this, $(this).text());
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/Bsq2T/1/)

You can also use delegate for better performance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-navlist').delegate('li a', 'click', function() {
        // alert($(this).text());
        searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this, $(this).text());
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/Bsq2T/2/)**

Comment: Thanks! Both options worked perfectly. I'm not familiar with delegate, so I'm not sure what the advantage is. I'll research that a bit, and decide which version to use. Thanks again.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-navlist').delegate("li", "click", function() {
        searchExhibitorsByAlphabet(this, $(this).text());
        return false;
    });
});
```

And change your HTML to:

```
<ul id="search-navlist">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    ....
    <li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks JMax. You solution is similar to Mrchief's. I'm going to look up how "delegate" works, so that I have a clearer understanding as to what's happening.

Comment: Indeed, we get inspired from each other (i took `$(this).text` and he took the delegate part :)). i'm glad you found what you were looking for. And don't forget to accept an answer if it fits your need by checking the tick on the left of the answer